# Scoping issue when moving code into another function - c++ SFML

Tags: c++, user-interface, scope, sfml

I'm trying to create a simple grid with some images.
Everything works fine when the initialization is in one function:

```
void gameLoop()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "Minesweeper", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> grid(DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM, std::vector<sf::Sprite>(DEFAULT_COLS_NUM));

    sf::Texture unrevealedEmptyTexture;
    if (!unrevealedEmptyTexture.loadFromFile("Images/unrevealed_empty.png"))
        return;

    // Set the position and scale of each sprite
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DEFAULT_COLS_NUM; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].setTexture(unrevealedEmptyTexture);
            grid[i][j].setPosition(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE);

            // Rescale to CELL_SIZE (multiply by CELL_SIZE / IMAGE_DIMENSION, for both x and y) 
            grid[i][j].setScale((float)CELL_SIZE / unrevealedEmptyTexture.getSize().x, (float)CELL_SIZE / unrevealedEmptyTexture.getSize().y);
        }
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        drawBoard(window, grid);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

But if I move the code that creates the sprite vectors to another function (in the same file):

```
std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> initGuiBoard()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> grid(DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM, std::vector<sf::Sprite>(DEFAULT_COLS_NUM));

    sf::Texture unrevealedEmptyTexture;
    if (!unrevealedEmptyTexture.loadFromFile("Images/unrevealed_empty.png"))
        return {};

    // Set the position and scale of each sprite
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DEFAULT_COLS_NUM; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j].setTexture(unrevealedEmptyTexture);
            grid[i][j].setPosition(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE);

            // Rescale to CELL_SIZE (multiply by CELL_SIZE / IMAGE_DIMENSION, for both x and y) 
            grid[i][j].setScale((float)CELL_SIZE / unrevealedEmptyTexture.getSize().x, (float)CELL_SIZE / unrevealedEmptyTexture.getSize().y);
        }
    }

    return grid;
}
```

And then call it:

```
void gameLoop()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "Minesweeper", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> guiGrid = initGuiBoard();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        drawBoard(window, guiGrid);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

The window is just plain white. I assume this has something to do with scoping, but I'm not really sure.
I know I can just go with the first option, but I want to seperate my code into functions.

Is there any way around this? thanks!

Comment: "`//window.clear(sf::Color::White);`" - Why did you comment out that line? With SFML you are supposed to *always* clear/draw/display.

Comment: Hm. I thought it was the cause of the blank window.
Okay, I uncommented it. Still the same problem though.... :

Comment: See https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.6.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php: The `Sprite` object requires that the `Texture` object passed to `setTexture` outlives the `Sprite` object. In your second version that is not the case.

Comment: Oh, I see. So what are my options? I can only think of 2, which are pass the texture to the function by reference, or use it as a global variable. Are there any other options? which is the best?

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed in comments, `Texture` is destroyed before the `Sprite` is used. This is because the `Texture` is created as a local variable in the `initGuiBoard` and is destroyed at the end of the function.

To fix this, you can return the `Texture` from `initGuiBoard`:

```cpp
pair<vector<vector<sf::Sprite>>, sf::Texture> initGuiBoard() {
    // ...
    return { grid, unrevealedEmptyTexture };
}
void gameLoop() {
    auto [ guiGrid, unrevealedEmptyTexture ] = initGuiBoard();
    // ...
}
```

Another option is to create the Texture in the `gameLoop` and pass it to `initGuiBoard` by reference:

```cpp
void gameLoop() {
    sf::Texture unrevealedEmptyTexture;
    if (!unrevealedEmptyTexture.loadFromFile("Images/unrevealed_empty.png"))
        return;
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>> guiGrid = initGuiBoard(unrevealedEmptyTexture);
    // ...
}
```

This ways, the Texture will be local `gameLoop` variable and will live until the end of this function.